# CharBuffer.put() didn't working

Tags: java, buffer, put

I try to put some strings to `CharBuffer` with `CharBuffer.put()` function
but the buffer is left blank.

my code:

```
CharBuffer charBuf = CharBuffer.allocate(1000);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
    String text = "testing" + i + "\n";
    charBuf.put(text);
}
System.out.println(charBuf);
```

I tried to use with `clear()` or `rewind()` after `allocate(1000)` but that did not change the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must rewind it after you put in the objects, try this

```
CharBuffer charBuf = CharBuffer.allocate(1000);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
    String text = "testing" + i + "\n";
    charBuf.put(text);
}
charBuf.rewind();
System.out.println(charBuf);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
CharBuffer charBuf = CharBuffer.allocate(1000);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
    String text = "testing" + i + "\n";
    charBuf.put(text);
}
charBuf.rewind();
System.out.println(charBuf);
```

The detail you're missing is that writing moves the current pointer to the end of the written data, so when you're printing it out, it's starting at the current pointer, which has nothing written.

Answer (score 3):

Add a call to [`rewind()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/Buffer.html#rewind%28%29) right **after** the loop.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to `flip()` the buffer before you can read from the buffer. The `flip()` method needs to be called before reading the data from the buffer. When the `flip()` method is called the limit is set to the current position, and the position to 0. e.g.

```
CharBuffer charBuf = CharBuffer.allocate(1000);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
{
    String text = "testing" + i + "\n";
    charBuf.put(text);
}
charBuf.flip();
System.out.println(charBuf);
```

The above will only print the characters in the buffers and not the unwritten space in the buffer.